# How to output a tweet URL in a user timeline using the Dukt Twitter plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-dukttwitter

I'm just trying out the [Dukt Twitter plugin](https://dukt.net/twitter/docs/installation). Is it possible to output a link to a tweet within a timeline? I've tried guessing {{ tweet.url }}, but that doesn't work. I don't want to auto-link the tweet itself using {{ tweet.text|autoLinkTweet) }}, as I'm wanting to output the entire tweet as plain text. I've included my code below and thanks for any help in advance.

```
{% set tweets = craft.twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', { screen_name:'craftcms', count: 3, trim_user: false }) %}

{% if tweets %}

  <h2>Recent Tweets</h2>

  <ul>
    {% for tweet in tweets %}
      <li><a href="{{ tweet.url }}">{{ tweet.text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, you got any solutions for this? I am having same problem but did not find anything. The DUKT plugin is deprecated.

Comment: I don't think I got anywhere with this so left it, sorry.

Comment: So you got anything else to fetch tweets on the Craft site?